# Javascript New User - onchange online firing once

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have a form that i'm working on that will dynamically hide any selections in an optgroup, everything works fine except that the onchange() only fires the initial time when initial selection is made.  I'm trying to make it so that the onchange() even fires every time that a user selects a new option.  The unhiding of the div and initial selection work like I said.

Help please!

```
   <script>
function toggleandhide() {
   var cont = document.getElementById('cont');
   if (cont.style.display == 'inline-block') {
       cont.style.display = 'none';
   }
   else {
       cont.style.display = 'inline-block';
   }
    var e = document.getElementById("vendor_id");
    var str = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    var groups = document.getElementsByTagName('optgroup');
        for (var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
            if (groups[i].label != str) {
                var options = groups[i].childNodes;
                    for (var j = 0; j < options.length; j++)
                        options[j].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
    </script>

echo "<div class=\"table\">";
echo "<div class=\"table-row\">";
echo "<div class=\"table-cell\">";
echo "Cruise Line:";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"table-cell\">";
echo "<div class=\"selectWrapper\">";
echo "<select class=\"selectBox\" name=\"vendor_id\" id=\"vendor_id\" onchange=\"toggleandhide()\">";
echo "<option value=\"\"></option>";
foreach($vendors as $key2 => $val2 ){
        echo "<option value=\"".$key2."\">".$val2."</option>";  
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";


echo "<div class=\"table\">";
echo "<div id=\"cont\" style=\"display: none;\" class=\"table-row\">";
echo "<div class=\"table-cell\">";
echo "Cruise Ship  :";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class=\"table-cell\" style=\"padding-left: 114px\">";
echo "<div class=\"selectWrapper\">";
echo "<select class=\"selectBox\" name=\"ship_id\">";
echo "<option value=\"\"></option>";
foreach($vendors as $r3 => $d3){
    foreach( $true_list as $k => $r ){
        if($d3==$vendor_name[$k]){
            if(!empty($vendor_name[$k])){
            echo "<optgroup label=\"".$vendor_name[$k]."\">";
            asort($r);
            foreach($r as $r2 => $d2){
                    echo "<option value=\"".$r2."\">".$d2."</option>";
                }
            echo "</optgroup>";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: do you get any console errors? also .. your PHP doing all those `echo` of static HTML can be greatly improved ... but that's not important now

Comment: Remove the parans() on your  onchange call, make it `onchange=\"toggleandhide\"`  
You should not call the function there, just tell the code which function to call.